# Css left side of a div brighter?

Tags: css, html, colors

I have a div which is a wrapper of my half website and on the left side there's a category list. The wrapper itself is in grey color.

What I want is that it would switch from grey color to white. Here's an example image how I'd like it to be:

[image]

Is there a solution to this?

**EDIT**

If it will be of any help here's my wrapper's css:

```
#wrapper{
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to add a gradient. Below you find the CSS for a gradient going from left to right with the colors `#FFFFFF` to `#F3F3F3`.

Please be aware, that gradients haven't been standardized yet, and many browsers have their own implementiation. This is why there are multiple directives (prefixed -o- for Opera, -moz- for Mozilla, etc.):

```
#wrapper {
    ...
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 35%, rgb(243,243,243) 84%);
    background-image: 
        -o-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 35%, rgb(243,243,243) 84%);
    background-image: 
        -moz-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 35%, rgb(243,243,243) 84%);
    background-image: 
        -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 35%, rgb(243,243,243) 84%);
    background-image: 
        -ms-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 35%, rgb(243,243,243) 84%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.35, rgb(255,255,255)),
        color-stop(0.84, rgb(243,243,243))
    );
}
```

Here's a convenient [CSS Gradient Generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

Comment: Good (+1), but  CSS-gradients are not yet implemented across all important browsers. See  http://caniuse.com/css-gradients for details on what browsers support it.

Comment: Note that does not work in IE8 and earlier without CSS3 PIE or something similar (which can potentially lead to performance problems)

Comment: +1 to both comments, thanks for the link and the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

What you need are gradients.
Try [this generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) or just read about them